# ststus 404 for returns in sap hybris, after installing the orderselfserviceaddon to storefornt

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice, impex

1.included in localextension.xml like this 

2.ant addoninstall -Daddonnames="orderselfserviceaddon" 3.DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront="rapidhybrisstorefront"
i installed it to the storefront and updated the system
still it showing 404 while accessing the returns page

Comment: Did you get any error during the addoninstall?

Answer (score 0):

After repeating all those steps, I restarted the server. Now, it's working fine.

Comment: Question: When you said it didn't work at first, did you run the addoninstall while the server was still running?  Did you build after the addoninstall?

Comment: after installing addon i rebuild the server

Comment: after few builds it was gone once again

Comment: That's good to know. I guess you can accept your own answer now. :)